# No container found in path - DOCKER

Tags: docker, path

I am trying to download a docker image called anchor-engine found at the following link: https://hub.docker.com/r/anchore/anchore-engine/

 For ease, I will post a copy of the code used to create the image and get it running as they have specified. 
[Here is a link to the image, I tried posting the image, but it requires reputation 10.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS9vR.png)

The issue I am having is specifically on this line of the download:
docker cp ae:/docker-compose.yaml ~/aevolume/docker-compose.yaml

I get the following error message from my terminal: 
Error: No such container:path: ae:/docker-compose.yaml

My question is how do I fix this?

I am not good at $PATH. 
After echoing $PATH with echo "$PATH", I just see a very messy blob of path and I do not really know how to create the necessary container in the directory specified, which was the first line mkdir ~/aevolume. 
The thing is it specifically requires a container and when I type ls, it gives a blank response. 
Please help and thanks.

The lines I have been able to run are:
mkdir ~/aevolume 
cd ~/aevolume

docker pull docker.io/anchore/anchore-engine:latest 
docker create --name ae docker.io/anchore/anchore-engine:latest

but when I try running 
docker cp ae:/docker-compose.yaml ~/aevolume/docker-compose.yaml

As I have done in this following line: 
aevolume admin$ docker cp ae:/docker-compose.yaml ~/aevolume/docker-compose.yaml

I get this response: 
Error: No such container:path: ae:/docker-compose.yaml

Comment: Please include the actual commands you ran as text in the question itself, not as an image.  (I can't run that screen shot to reproduce the issue.)

Comment: Did the `docker pull` & `docker create` work as expected? Or did you not run it? The `ae` container will be created by docker create, so seems some steps were missed or failed.

Comment: Thanks I updated the post with the lines I ran as per your suggestion. Hope it helps to figure out how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like there's an issue with the latest version of the Anchore image that was updated 14 days ago. I've been experiencing the same issue. I went ahead and used version 0.7.0 for the commands and it worked fine:

```
mkdir ~/aevolume
cd ~/aevolume

docker pull anchore/anchore-engine:v0.7.0
docker create --name ae anchore/anchore-engine:v0.7.0
docker cp ae:/docker-compose.yaml ~/aevolume/docker-compose.yaml
```

Hopefully this helps, I was stuck on it for a bit haha.

Answer (score 0):

@Sandeep Kumar There is a correction in the last command.

```
docker cp ae:/docker-compose.yaml ~/aevolume/docker-compose.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to get docker-compose.yaml for anchore, try this:

`curl https://docs.anchore.com/current/docs/engine/quickstart/docker-compose.yaml > docker-compose.yaml`

Here is the reference:
https://docs.anchore.com/current/docs/engine/quickstart/

It worked well for myself after I ran into the same issue as described above.